# MvvmCross iOS UITableView doesn't update on Property Changed

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

My table view does not update whenever its source property is changed. The code is as follows:

ViewController:

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

        var table = new UITableView(new RectangleF(0, 80, Device.Width, Device.Height - 80));
        Add(table);
        var source = new MvxStandardTableViewSource(table, "TitleText SessionInfo");
        table.Source = source;

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<JoinSessionViewController, JoinSessionViewModel>();
        set.Bind(source).To(vm => vm.AvailableServers);
        set.Apply();

        table.ReloadData();
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
    private readonly INetworkSessionClient _client;

    public JoinSessionViewModel(INetworkSessionClient client)
    {
        _client = client;

        _client.ServerFound += ClientOnServerFound;
        _client.BeginSearchingForServers();
    }

    private void ClientOnServerFound(object sender, ServerFoundEventArgs serverFoundEventArgs)
    {
        if (AvailableServers.Any(s => s.Identifier == serverFoundEventArgs.ServerInfo.Identifier))
            return;

        AvailableServers.Add(serverFoundEventArgs.ServerInfo);
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => AvailableServers);
    }

    private List<ServerInfo> _availableServers;
    public List<ServerInfo> AvailableServers
    {
        get { return _availableServers; }
        set { _availableServers = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => AvailableServers); }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a tricky one. The culprit is this line in MvxTableViewSource:

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/MvxTableViewSource.cs#L56

```
    public virtual IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return _itemsSource; }
        set
        {
            if (_itemsSource == value) // **** This one ****
                return;

            if (_subscription != null)
            {
                _subscription.Dispose();
                _subscription = null;
            }

            _itemsSource = value;

            var collectionChanged = _itemsSource as INotifyCollectionChanged;
            if (collectionChanged != null)
            {
                _subscription = collectionChanged.WeakSubscribe(CollectionChangedOnCollectionChanged);
            }

            ReloadTableData();
        }
    }
```

Since I was only adding to the list and not setting it to a new list, the setter was early returning and not firing ReloadTableData(). The fix was to use an ObservableCollection (or anything else that implements INotifyCollectionChanged) instead of a List.

```
    private void ClientOnServerFound(object sender, ServerFoundEventArgs serverFoundEventArgs)
    {
        if (AvailableServers.Any(s => s.Identifier == serverFoundEventArgs.ServerInfo.Identifier))
            return;

        // CollectionChanged event is not automatically martialed to UI thread
        InvokeOnMainThread(() => AvailableServers.Add(serverFoundEventArgs.ServerInfo));
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ServerInfo> _availableServers;
    public ObservableCollection<ServerInfo> AvailableServers
    {
        get { return _availableServers; }
        set { _availableServers = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => AvailableServers); }
    }
```

Note that because of my particular case, the ServerFound event is being invoked on a separate thread. That means the INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged event will also be invoked on a separate thread, so the action of adding the server to the list has to be martialed onto the main thread with InvokeOnMainThread() so that the UI will properly update.

It would be nice if CollectionChanged events would automatically be handled on the UI thread, similar to how RaisePropertyChanged() works.

Comment: This has come up before - e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170151/items-not-showing-in-mvxlistview/18181316#18181316 - the reason-for-being behind the `==` line of code is an optimisation (to prevent multiple list drawing). If anyone thinks this could or should be done somehow better (e.g. making it optional, adding some trace, or something else) then please do log an issue about it or send a Pull Request.

Comment: Observable Collection runs in Exception with RecyclerView: "Exception masked during Adapter RealNotifyDataSetChanged ArgumentException: 'jobject' must not be IntPtr.Zero". Simple solution ist to change back to List and if you delete or add an item, call .ToList()