# MvvmCross MvxListView not refreshing on item delete

Tags: c#, viewmodel, mvvmcross

When I remove an item from my list, the MvxListView does not refresh.

My list (nothing fancy):

```
private List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
public List<Item> Items 
{ 
     get { return items; } 
     set { items = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Items); } 
}
```

The code that doesn't work:

```
Items.RemoveAll(x => x.Id == item.Id);
RaisePropertyChanged(() => Items);
```

Code that does work:

```
Items = Items.Where(x => x.Id != item.Id).ToList();
```

It seems like the `RaisePropertyChanged()` function does not have the desired effect when being called from a isolated function within the viewmodel, but why?

Comment: Just tried and RaisePropertyChanged() works fine, so I think you have some issue with mvvmcross if it didn't work on your side. I'm using MvvmCross 3.0.14

Comment: Switch to using an observable collection instead of a list. Or, for more info, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22161149/mvvmcross-ios-uitableview-doesnt-update-on-property-changed/22161150#22161150

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an ObservableCollection to make the MvxListView update the content.

```
private ObservableCollection<Item> items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items 
{ 
     get { return items; } 
     set { items = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Items); } 
}
```