# MvxGridView propertychanged on collection not working

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm quite new to mvvmcross. I've been binding a collection of Users in my viewmodel to a MvxGridView.

Initially, the binding works as the grid nicely displays the users from the ItemsSource. But when I scroll down, I'm loading more users, add it to the Users collection and then do a RaisePropertyChanged on the collection. But nothing seems to happen, the same users get displayed while the underlying collection has changed. Do I need to do anything special with collections for the binding to work? Or do I need to redraw the gridview somehow?

Comment: I think this is the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170151/items-not-showing-in-mvxlistview/18181316#18181316 0 uf tiy are adding to a list, then consider using ObservableCollection

Comment: Sorry about the typos in that last comment - looks like a keyboard-finger out by one error! Also wanted to add that the next release will include https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/619 - but I don't think that is the best solution for your current problem.

Comment: Observablecollection did the trick. I think I was tired or something because I'm very familiar with those. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an ObservableCollection to make the MvxGridView update the content.

```
private ObservableCollection<Item> items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items 
{ 
     get { return items; } 
     set { items = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Items); } 
}
```